# Storing custom properties in resx files in Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, localization, properties, resx

We are developing a CF application and are making use of the default localization/resource handling in the framework (that is, when editing a form in the designer properties like Text have their value stored in the .resx files and the resource manager and framework loads it for us again in the selected locale using satelite assemblies and a call to ApplyResources in the .Designer file)

We have a few custom controls and one of these includes a string property called EditTitle. We would like this value to be stored in the resx file when editing the designer to get the same localization support as the Text property but we can't find anywhere to specify this. We do have an .xmta file for other designtime attributes but we can't find any element in there that would trigger this behavior.

Are there any way to specify this behavior for the particular property. Is it possible to do this for our own properties or is Visual Studio hardwired to only work with a known set of properties and we should be looking for other solutions (like editing the resx file by hand and hoping that the ApplyResources-call picks up and applies the EditTitle property)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, discovered the solution (was pretty self-evident, actually). You can add the following attribute via the DesignTimeAttributes.xmta file:

```
<Property Name="EditTitle">
  <Localizable>true</Localizable>
</Property>
```

This Localizable attribute will make sure that the value entered in the designer ends up in the .resx file