# .NET localize custom control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a customer textbox that inherits from the standard textbox. This textbox has a string property for 'cue', which displays a short message in the textbox in light gray when there's no text. This custom control is in a separate assembly.

Now I want to localize my forms, and these forms include my custom textbox. The problem is that the 'cue' property is not being saved in the form's resx file for the specific language.

How can I set up Visual Studio to save the text in my 'cue' property in the resx files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms/4902969#4902969

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding:

```
[Localizable(true)]
```

to the localizable properties of the custom control.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading this threads, may be can help you:
[Storing custom properties in resx files in Compact Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185290/storing-custom-properties-in-resx-files-in-compact-framework)

[Adding custom properties to strings in resx](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb2b6358-091c-4eb5-b834-1d50e82c1baf/adding-custom-properties-to-strings-in-resx-in-visual-studio-20052008?forum=vsx)

[Localizing ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42168/Localizing-ASP-NET-MVC)

Visual Studio use the System.Resources.ResXResourceReader and System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter to read and write resource to the resource file (.resx). To add custom columns, I think you need to provide you own ResourceReader, ResourceWriter and the editor. With that now, you can do reference.